# Switching to Pygame Fullscreen Mode working only one time

Tags: python, pygame, fullscreen

I'm new to the pygame.FULLSCREEN mode, and I need your help.
I'm writing a small game, in which the player is supposed to be able to switch between normal mode and full screen mode.

When I run my program is that the window opens, and when I click on the maximize button I get into full screen mode. When I press escape, I get back to normal mode. Everything's working fine so far.

But when I click the maximize button a second time the window is *maximized*, however, I do not get into full screen mode. Also, the part of the window that pygame uses remains normal size.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 500
height = 500

info = pygame.display.Info()
screen_width = info.current_w
screen_height = info.current_h

window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)

fullscreen = False

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            window = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
            fullscreen = True

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE] and fullscreen:
            window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
            fullscreen = False

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pygame.VIDEORESIZE` is executed every time when the window is resized. Hence even if the window is changed to a smaller size, then `pygame.VIDEORESIZE` occurs.
Get the new size of the window by `event.set` and create a new `pygame.FULLSCREEN` or `pygame.FULLSCREEN` display dependent on the current state 
 of `fullscreen`. But set `fullscreen` by a key, for instance <kbd>f</kbd>. [`pygame.event.post()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.post) a new [`pygame.event.Event()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) with the proper arguments:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            type = pygame.FULLSCREEN if fullscreen else pygame.RESIZABLE
            window = pygame.display.set_mode(event.size, type)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if not fullscreen and event.key == pygame.K_f:
                fullscreen = True
                pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(pygame.VIDEORESIZE, size = (screen_width, screen_height)))
            if fullscreen and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                fullscreen = False
                pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(pygame.VIDEORESIZE, size = (width, height)))

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.display.update()
```